# uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Worker (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, sidekiq

Today I discovered the [sidekiq-mailer](https://github.com/andersondias/sidekiq_mailer), a wonderful gem that integrates with Sidekiq and really can help my project. But I'm having some issues in installation/configuration, someone can help me? I already saw all related questions and none fix my issue.

---

### Gem File

Currently I'm using the lastest version of Sidekiq and the lastest version of SidekiqMailer. Following you can check my gemfile:

```
gem 'sidekiq'
gem "sidekiq-cron" 
gem 'sidekiq-failures' 
gem 'sidekiq_mailer', git: 'https://github.com/andersondias/sidekiq_mailer.git'
```

I'm using all this gems, but in different purposes / features.

---

### Files

I have two workers at the moment: one that uses "sidekiq" + "sidekiq-cron" and another (I think you have a good guess) that uses "sidekiq" + "sidekiq_mailer".

I have one **PersonMailer**, but this don't use "sidekiq_mailer" yet:

```
class PersonMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "no-reply@myAwesomeProject.com"

  # Templates in "views/mailers/mailer_name/method_name.html.erb"
  default template_path: "mailers/#{self.name.underscore}"

  def send_email_new_user(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "You = <3")
  end

end
```

And I call my mailer this way (inside PersonController):

```
PersonMailer.send_email_new_user(user).deliver
```

---

### The Error

Now let's talk about my error. After I run `bundle install` in Terminal, I can't start my localhost server (`rails s`). Always I try it I receive the following error:

```
/home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/bundler/gems/sidekiq_mailer-4a5881b10c2a/lib/sidekiq_mailer/worker.rb:2:in `<class:Worker>': uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Worker (NameError)
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/bundler/gems/sidekiq_mailer-4a5881b10c2a/lib/sidekiq_mailer/worker.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/bundler/gems/sidekiq_mailer-4a5881b10c2a/lib/sidekiq_mailer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/bundler-1.6.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/paladini/Documents/Programacao/myAwesomeProject/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/paladini/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@myAwesomeProject/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

## How can I solve this problem fast?

**P.S:** I also posted this question as a GitHub Issue, [here](https://github.com/andersondias/sidekiq_mailer/issues/17).

Comment: What is the benefit of `sidekiq-mailer` over Sidekiq's [built-in](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions#actionmailer) ability to email asynchronously? Perhaps you can just remove `sidekiq-mailer`.

Comment: But what about that: "This feature is for compatibility with DelayedJob, I recommend you use Sidekiq's native Workers where possible."? Actually I don't understand the meaning of this phrase. I need install / configure something called "DelayedJob" to this built-in ability works correctly? If so, how?

Comment: You're right, I removed the statement.  It's overly aggressive.  .delay is designed to make sending async emails trivial.

Comment: Oh, hello Mike! So, I don't need any gem to make async e-mails? I just need sidekiq installed and a line like `UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(@user.id)`, without any additional gem?

Comment: It is recommending that you wrap your mailing logic in a worker, but you can send emails out asynchronously by doing `UserMailer.delay.send_email_new_user(user.id)`